# Loading a php file into div using ajax

Tags: php, jquery, ajax

I've been stuck on a project for a few days now, and the part I need to do I'm lost on.

I'm trying to get a .php file that contains just a form to load into a div using AJAX. I've been researching through all the old posts, and everything I've tried just doesn't work, and the examples have left me more confused in some aspects. I'm using XAMPP, and have it so a user has to log in through the DB, and get to their profile. When they're in the profile they can click "Add a to-do" and it should bring up a Form which is located in toDoForm.php.

**profile.php**

```
<div class="col s4">
    <button id="loadToDoForm" type="submit">Add a To-Do</button>
</div>
<div id="toDoFormShow">
    // toDoForm.php goes here on button click
</div>
```

**toDoForm.php**

```
<form class="col s12">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="input-field col s6">
            <input placeholder="Placeholder" id="first_name" type="text" class="validate">
            <label for="first_name">First Name</label>
        </div>
        <div class="input-field col s6">
            <input id="last_name" type="text" class="validate">
            <label for="last_name">Last Name</label>
        </div>
    </div>
</form>
```

Here is where I try to run ajax on the button click

**script.js**

```
$(document).ready(function(){

    $('#loadToDoForm').click(function(){
        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: "toDoForm.php",
            // url: "views/toDoForm.php",
            data: datas,
            cache: false,
            success: function(html){
            }
        });
    });

});
```

Comment: you have to echo the contain in php file instead current one and then append to the element

Answer (score 0):

How about a jQuery solution as you're using it anyway? You don't really need server side for this.

You can use this for many different sections of your site.

Create a file named e.g. `siteTemplates.html` - this will hold template sections, e.g. your form

Add your form html and give it an id:

```
<form class="col s12" id="myFormTemplate"><!-- notice ID -->
    <div class="row">
        <div class="input-field col s6">
            <input placeholder="Placeholder" id="first_name" type="text" class="validate">
            <label for="first_name">First Name</label>
        </div>
        <div class="input-field col s6">
            <input id="last_name" type="text" class="validate">
            <label for="last_name">Last Name</label>
        </div>
    </div>
</form>
```

Function to load the template

```
loadTemplate(containerID, templateID){
    var myContainer = $('#' + containerID); // cache the container
    /* load just the section you need by specifying id within templates file */
    myContainer.load('/siteTemplates.html #' + templateID);
}
```

Then call the function on click

```
$('#loadToDoForm').click(loadTemplate('toDoFormShow', 'myFormTemplate'))
```

This is untested but should give you a starting block

Comment: I can't seem to get this to work, and I'm not sure if its because I don't have things in the right spots. Should the `siteTemplates.html` be inside any particular folder in the MVC and should I be calling it on `index.php` with include? I currently have it by itself in the project folder. And I'm just calling it with the jquery you provided and  nothing seems to happen when I click. Not sure how to figure out what the problem is.

Comment: The templates file will need the right path to access it - I've shown it here at root, so wherever your main `index.html` is, that is where it would go, otherwise adjust the path - what's your file structure?